# Merge results from two separate columns into one elongated column

Tags: sql, oracle, select

My table:

```
ID       Name     Status1     Status2
-------------------------------------
 1       foo       bar        grain
 2       bar       foo        sball
 3       foo       bar        grain
 4       far       boo        sball
```

I need for it to actually come out like this:

```
ID      Name      Status    
-------------------------------
 1       foo       bar       
 1       foo       grain
 2       bar       foo       
 2       bar       sball
 3       foo       bar       
 3       foo       bar
 4       far       boo       
 4       far       sball
```

How would I go about doing that and can you explain why?

I have tried concat but that is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `union all` (or `union`, it depends on what you want to get in case `Status1` and `Status2` are the same):

```
select ID, Name, Status1 as Status from tbl
union all
select ID, Name, Status2 from tbl
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66ef90/2)

Comment: Why are you doing a select ID, Name twice?

Comment: because `union` and `union all` work this way – they combine results from two select statements with the same number of fields, you can read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). By the way, you can add `order by ID` after the query above, to get the exact sorted output you've posted.

Comment: Does status2 have to be written as something? I tried the given query and I'm only getting one column but it's not adding results from status2. I also tried writing status2 as status and that is not showing me the results from the 2nd column in the new column.

Comment: I don't know what can be the problem, the query should work perfectly fine. And no, you don't need to give alias in the second select. You see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.html), maybe you've missed something.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault. It was the order by. I had an order by within the original table and I don't know why it didn't order it automatically again on the union all but that's what made the difference. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
WITH counter AS
   (SELECT LEVEL lvl FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2)
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.NAME
      ,CASE c.lvl
         WHEN 1 THEN t.status1
         WHEN 2 THEN t.status2
       END status
FROM   test_table t
CROSS JOIN counter c;
```

The hierarchical query is something you'll see quite often on http://asktom.oracle.com/ to produce a list of numbers. The cross join returns a row for every combination of the rows in the joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot

```
    select * from tbl t unpivot (Status for col in(Status1, Status2));
```